# utility to troubleshoot PC not going idle

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I have Windows 7 x64 installed and sometimes it will not go into an idle state allowing for the monitor to turn off.  I keep shutting down services and programs, but I can't pinpoint what is causing the issue.  Is there a utility that I can run that will tell me if the mouse is moving or something is resetting the idle period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

> powercfg -energy

will scan your system and give a full report on the power state. Look for any errors or warnings in the output.